# Generalizing $x^\intercal A x = 0$ theorems to $x^\intercal A(x) x = 0$ forms?

Tags: matrix-equations, quadratic-forms, symmetric-matrices

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be any real vector and let$\ A = A^\intercal \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}\ $ be a real symmetric matrix. Then,
$$
x^\intercal A x = 0\ \ \ \forall x \ \ \implies \ \ A \equiv 0
$$

Can we still say this if $\ A = A^\intercal : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}\ $ is a real symmetric matrix-valued function of $x$? I.e.,
$$
x^\intercal A(x) x = 0\ \ \ \forall x \ \ \overset{?}{\implies} \ \ A \equiv 0\ \ \ \forall x
$$

Also, is there a name for equations of the form $f(x) = x^\intercal A(x) x$ with symmetric $A$? It is obviously not quadratic since $A$ depends on $x$, but it still has a certain quadratic-form feel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, found a counter-example. The matrix $A$ just needs to have an eigenvector of $x$ with eigenvalue 0, or put another way, $x$ just has to be in the null-space of $A$. This is obvious to construct in 2D, but of course applies generally. Let,
$$x := \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{bmatrix}$$

Find a vector orthogonal to $x$ and call it $v$.
$$v(x) := \begin{bmatrix} x_2 \\ -x_1 \end{bmatrix}$$

Construct the following matrix by outer-product,
$$A(x) := vv^T = \begin{bmatrix} x_2^2 & -x_1x_2 \\ -x_1x_2 & x_1^2 \end{bmatrix}$$

This matrix is symmetric $\forall x$, is not the zero matrix, but still satisfies $x^TAx = 0,\ \ \forall x$.

Answer (score 0):

## Starting with what you already know

Imagine a vector $y = Ax$. If $x^T y = 0$, then either $x \perp y$, or either $y$ or $x$ must be $0$. So $A$ must be the composition of a rotation by $\pi / 2$ about some axis in any number of dimensions and any scaling. Just imagine the composition of an arbitrary number of [Givens Rotations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Givens_rotation). We can impose more stringent requirements, but we won't bother.

A rotation other than the identity cannot be symmetric. A fine property of matrices representing rotations is that $A^T = A^{-1}$. If $A = A^T$ then $A=I$ which is not a rotation by $\pi / 2$ about anything.

## Fine

So we've shown that $A$ cannot spawn $y \perp x$. Therefore, if $x^T y=0$ then $y = 0$ or $x = 0$. If $y=0$ for any $x \neq 0$ then $A = 0$.

Let's ignore for a moment that $A$ is a function of $x$. If we have **any** $A$, produced by a drawing from a hat,

Assume there is a function $ A(x) $ for which $ x^T(t) A(x,t) x(t) = 0 $ but $ A(x, t) \neq 0 $. By the above, we are claiming that either:

1. $A(x, t)x(t) \perp x \;\; \forall_{x, t}$

or

2. $A(x, t) = 0$.

We know that 1. must be false, because $A^T = A$, so 2. must be true.

Comment: That's exactly what I thought at first! However, I found a counter-example. See my self-answer.

Comment: I think what we both missed is the possibility that $x$ be in the null-space of $A(x)$.